# attaching event dp.change to dynamic bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have an html table with multiple registers, each of these have a *Bootstrap datetimepicker* in which the user can edit a given date. So, as I said before, I generated them dynamically and I need to attach to everyone of them a method *onchange* with *JQuery*. Right now I have this:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (ev) {
            alert('hey that works!');
        });
```

and the HTML code is:

```
<div class='input-group date' name="datepicker" id='datetimepicker{{$contract->id}}' >
      <input type='text' class="form-control" id="fecha"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
             </span>
      </span>
</div>
```

So, as you can see in the JQuery I only have the code for the datetimepicker with id `datetimepicker6`  but I need it to every datepicker. I cannot put the same id to everyone, so I was thinking in put them the same *name* an then in JQuery get the array of elements with that name and attach the event *dp.change*  So, how can I do it?
I also tried:

```
$('input[name="datepicker"]').each(function() {
            $(this).datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (ev) {
                alert('hey it works"');
            });
});
```

But nothing changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By seeing at your code, its clear that when your trying to add jquery to a static element is working fine but while making it dynamic your facing issues. This is because in static part you are using the id of the input "Parent" that is 'datetimepicker6' but while making it dynamic you are adding the code to input itself hence its not working.

Help :

```
$('.input-group.date').each(function() {
            $(this).datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (ev) {
                alert('hey it works"');
            });
});
```

-Thanks